# Error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'ODP' of undefined" on node-red

Tags: scripting, node-red

I'm developing a program in node-red that gets tags from a database and should then "write" the value of them on a connected plc, but some tags are not passed due to this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'ODP' of undefined" the script inside the node that from error is the following :

"msg.payload = {"value":[''+msg.payload[0].ODP+'']};
return msg;"

the tags are : OPD (string[30]) , DATA(string[10] , QUANT_INIZIALE DINT , QUANT_PROD DINT

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error implies  that your input `msg.payload` to the  function node is not an array.

It is not possible to see in the image you have posted, exactly which node the error is happening on, but if you attach a debug node before point you should be able to see what the input message looks like.

Comment: I found the error for the first tag was the offset did not coincide with the actual one in the plc

Comment: fixed all , the problem was one offset that did not coincide with the actual one in the plc and i think this create problem for the other tags, now I'm testing everything to see if the program works properly